# Creating wordpress loop - Use get_template_part or use functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am creating custom loops to then create a "dynamic" looking website (different modules that can be called to make each page look different).

My question is, what is the proper way to do this with loops.

Do I create a separate template file for each module based on the original loop.php with name variants and call them with get_template_part? Or do I simply create a function for each module and call them in with the function name?

I think both would work, so confused which route to go down.

P.s  By modules I mean that the homepage (for example) can put multiple different looking blocks with a loop of posts presented differently (think theverge.com) and make a custom homepage

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "modules". That isn't a term used by WordPress, and you didn't really define it.

**Edit:** Based on a comment below, it sounds like you might mean by "modules" what WordPress refers to as ["widgets"](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets). Though frequently referred to a "sidebar widgets" you can put these anywhere you want, not just on the side. These would be the other way to swap out content dynamically, but in a different way. Widgets can be added or removed from the backend as desired.

Generally, though, use [`get_template_part`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part). It provides largely equivalent functionality (but not identical) to creating functions for each of your theme parts and also allows [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to over-write functionality. If a child theme adds a template part of the same name as a parent template part, the child theme's part get used. That can be pretty convenient. Using core functions where you can also helps make your code more robust over time, as WordPress core code changes.

Comment: By modules I mean that the homepage (for example) can put multiple different looking blocks with a loop of posts presented differently (think theverge.com) and make a custom homepage. But thanks for your answer, I think I might go for get template part, unless someone else has a good reason not to!

Answer (score 0):

First option is better because meaningful file names will be easier to use and understand in get_template_part(). Normally we play with content.php but when you will go for more views or further child modules so prefixes in file names will play important role.